# Getting Data From Rows Comparing it However All Cells Gets Updated

Tags: javascript, html

good day so we encontered a problem witho ur javascript problem
what it does is that it gets the data of rows and puts it in an array. and compares it
if its empty the inner text becomes "pay" otherwise "paid" here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var arr = [];
    var arr2 = [];
    var oTable = document.getElementById('example');

    //gets rows of table
    var rowLength = oTable.rows.length;

    //loops through rows    
    for (i = 0; i < rowLength; i++){

      //gets cells of current row  
       var oCells = oTable.rows.item(i).cells;

       //gets amount of cells of current row
       var cellLength = 1;

       //loops through each cell in current row
       for(var j = 0; j < cellLength; j++){

              // get your cell info here

              var cellVal = oCells.item(1).innerText;
              arr.push(cellVal);
           }
    }


    for (a = 0; a < rowLength; a++){

      //gets cells of current row  
       var oCells = oTable.rows.item(a).cells;

       //gets amount of cells of current row
       var cellLength = 1;

       //loops through each cell in current row
       for(var b = 0; b < cellLength; b++){

              // get your cell info here

              var cellVal = oCells.item(7).innerText;
              console.log(oCells.item(7).innerText);

              if (arr[b] == '') {
                oCells.item(7).innerText = "Pay";
              } else {
                oCells.item(7).innerText = "Paid";
              }    

              arr2.push(cellVal);
       }
    }
    });
```

this script  does what is said above, this is actually taken from another source we tried to incorporate on our software, but yeah
it doesn't work the way we want it to.

It does make the change but the change happens for all the cells instead of one. we tried to generate it in the inspec console however we see our rows were clearly generated.

Any help is appreciated. Thankyou very much!

Comment: Please rethink and restate your problem. Your code is not appropriated at all as it features unnecessary loops, assignments and unappropriated tests. You should review your problem from the beginning and construct a pseudo code algorithm to solve it before implementing it.

Comment: Also, what's that hard-coded `7` in `oCells.item(7)`? Please provide a [mcve] and a clear statement of your problem.